# Exporting image data with bcp in sql2000

Tags: blob, sql-server-2000, docx, bcp

Hi I have a a sql 2000 database with a large number of scanned documents stored as pdfs and word documents stored in an image data type.
I need to export them to files.
I have written code to to do this using xp_cmdshell and bcp. Looking at other questions I have created a fmt file as below:

```
8.0
1
1       SQLIMAGE      0       0       ""                        1     FILEDATA        ""
```

the command is

```
bcp "select filedata FROM attacheddocuments where pkey = '+ convert (varchar, @imageid) + '" queryout "c:\scans\' + @imagefilename + '"  -T  -f c:\scans\attached.fmt
```

however when I run the query it creates all the files but they cannot be opened in either word or acrobat. both report that the file is corrupt.
If instead I run the command

```
bcp "select filedata FROM attacheddocuments where pkey = '+ convert (varchar, @imageid) + '" queryout "c:\scans\' + @imagefilename + '"  -T  -N
```

The pdf files now open ok but the word documents are still corrupt.
Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Having investigated this further I have found that using the -N flag on BCP only some of the pdf files will open. At the start of the pdf files that do not open all start with SPISLH5 (hex 53 50 49 53 1A 4C 48 35). Does any body know why?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post, I am having this issue with all files except PDF's.

I have tried without the -N and with. Using a format file and not using a format file.  Strange thing is I used to use my script often, had not used it for a while. During that period some SQL updates have came out. Not the scripts only exports PDF documents not being corrupt.

Zip files and just about any file I can run through a repair tool and they are fixed. But that is not a doable option due to volume.

[format file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXw6X.png)

Plus My format file had a 4 instead of 0. That alone made all files but PDF's documents corrupt with corrupt headers.

Comment: Found out the issue: My format file had a 4 instead of 0. That alone made all files but PDF's documents corrupt with corrupt headers.

Comment: Hi Jay, an answer should really be an answer. Add your comment to your answer to make it a real answer.